# React Native - this.updateTimeState is not a function. Trying to reference class method within another method?

Tags: javascript, function, reactjs, methods, react-native

I was hoping someone could help me out here please, I have looked around and cant find a solution to this in a way I understand, I come from a python background and have started to learn javascript again and now react-native, so of course Im doing so tutorials! As you might imagine it can be quite confusing, I was following a tutorial which was using the "React.createClass()" function, To better understand everything I wanted use the "class StopWatchNew extends Component" ES6 method which for me seems tidier and more logical (Let me know if there are better ways, im still confused about it all)

Anyway, Im trying to reference my class method within my class, like so;

```
   static updateTimeState() {
     var startTime = new Date();

     this.setState({
       timeElapsed: new Date() - this.startTime
     });
   };

   handleStartPress() {
     this.updateTimeState()
   };
```

And running this line, react-native throws this error

```
this.updateTimeState()
```

> this.updateTimeState is not a function. (In
>   'this.updateTimeState()','this.updateTimeState' is undefined)

I am confused because referencing the class methods in the JSX render method doesn't seem to be an issue.. I understand python is very different to JS but this is basically what I want to do if that helps.

```
class MyClass(object):
  def myFunc(self):
    pass

  self.myFunc()
```

Any help is appreciated Thanks!!

Example code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import formatTime from 'minutes-seconds-milliseconds'
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight,
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet
 } from 'react-native';

 class StopWatchNew extends Component {
  //  Setting the inital state
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {timeElapsed: null};


     var startTime = new Date();
   }

   border(color) {
     return (
       {
         borderColor: color,
         borderWidth: 4
       }
     )
   };

   startStopButton() {
     return (
       <TouchableHighlight
         underlayColor="grey"
         onPress={this.handleStartPress}>
         <Text>
           Start
         </Text>
       </TouchableHighlight>
     )
   };

   lapButton() {
     return (
       <View>
         <Text>
           Lap
         </Text>
       </View>
     )
   };

   static updateTimeState() {
     var startTime = new Date();

     this.setState({
       timeElapsed: new Date() - this.startTime
     });
   };

   handleStartPress() {
     this.updateTimeState()
   };

   render() {
     return (
       <View style={styles.container}>
         <View style={styles.statusBar}></View>
         <View style={[styles.header, this.border('yellow')]}>
           <View style={[this.border('red'), styles.timerWrapper]}>
             <Text>{this.state.timeElapsed}</Text>
           </View>
           <View style={[this.border('green'), styles.buttonWrapper]}>
             {this.startStopButton()}
             {this.lapButton()}
           </View>
         </View>
         <View style={[styles.footer, this.border('blue')]}>
           <Text>
             I am lap
           </Text>
         </View>
       </View>
     )
   };
 }

 var styles = StyleSheet.create({
   statusBar: {
     flex:0.08,
   },
   container: {
     flex: 1,
     alignItems: 'stretch'
   },
   header: { // Yellow
     flex: 1
   },

   footer: { // Blue
     flex: 1
   },

   timerWrapper: { // Red
     flex: 5,
     justifyContent: 'center',
     alignItems: 'center'

   },

   buttonWrapper: { // Green
     flex: 3,
     flexDirection: 'row',
     justifyContent: 'space-around',
     alignItems: 'center'
   }
 })

 export default StopWatchNew;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `this.handleStartPress` as a callback for an event handler. Since react ES6 don't bind callbacks automatically, `this.handleStartPress` is called in the context of the event handler, and `this` doesn't refer to the `StopWatchNew` class instance.

Manually bind `this.handleStartPress` to class instance's `this` in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {timeElapsed: null};

    var startTime = new Date();

    this.handleStartPress = this.handleStartPress.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! I tried this earlier but must have had something else broken at the time, Cheers.

Comment: great, upvote .. I need a consultation: as a top user in *react native* tag, do you think is learning it worthy?! Someone says it's perfect, someone else says that's a terrible idea .. So I'm confused, I want to make a mobile application (both for Android and iOS operation systems), well, is it possible to make professional apps by *react native*? Or react native just lets us to make beginner apps? Also what about the quality of apps which have been created by *react native*? thanks

Comment: @Shafizadeh - I'm more into desktop react then react native, so I'm not the one to ask.